# Modify Observable with another Observable and return the initial Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to return a ClientDetails object with a loaded image.

So retrieve an Observable, and modify the value with another Observable and return the whole Observable.

I hope the code below indicates what I am trying to do, but I know it can be done much cleaner using RxJS operators. Anyone know how to?

```
interface ClientDetails {
   team: Member[];
}

interface Member {
   id: number;
   image: string;
}


this.clientDetails$ = this.clientService.getClientDetails().subscribe((details: ClientDetails) => {
   details.team.forEach(member => {
      this.imageService.getImage(member.id).subscribe((image: string) => {
         member.image = image
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? As tip: You might want to use `merge` and  `switchMap`

Comment: 1) Please post any code updates in the question. It's almost impossible to read the code in the comments. 2) The property names b/n this code and the original question is different. There is no `this._client` argument and property `personId` in the question. It's better to keep the code consistent. It'd avoid confusion to both you and people trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in assuming RxJS operators would make it more elegant. At the moment the variable `this.clientDetails$` doesn't hold an observable and it wouldn't work as you'd expect it to.

Instead you could use higher order mapping operator `switchMap` to switch from one observable to another (it's better to avoid nested subscriptions in general) and `forkJoin` function to trigger multiple observables in parallel. You could also use JS destructing and RxJS `map` operator to return the object with all it's contents.

Try the following

```js
this.clientDetails$ = this.clientService.getClientDetails().pipe(
  switchMap((details: ClientDetails) =>
    forkJoin(
      details.team.map(member => 
        this.imageService.getImage(member.id).pipe(
          map(image: string => ({...member, member.image: image}))
        )
      )
    ).pipe(
      map((team: any) => ({...details, details.team: team}))
    )
  );
);
```

Note: I didn't test the code. Please check if the object returned is what you actually require.

Comment: It doesn't work this way. The pipe and map from image to member (line 4 and 5), should be on this.imageService.getImage observable, otherwise member is out of scope in mapping image to member + image.
Anyway the general principle is correct and works well once fixed.
Thanks

Comment: Good catch. Must've been in a hurry to wrongly pipe to `Array#map`. I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.clientDetails$ = this.clientService.getClientDetails().pipe(
  switchMap((details: ClientDetails) => {
    const images$: Observable<string[]> = forkJoin(
     details.team.map(member => this.imageService.getImage(member.id))
    );

    return forkJoin([of(details), images$]);
  }),
  map(([details, images]) => {
    return {
      team: _.zipWith(details.team, images, (d, m) => d.image = m) // zipWith = lodash function
    };
  }),
).subscribe((details: ClientDetails) => console.log(details));
```